# select random char in string by Index

Tags: c#, indexing, char

I am trying to see if a the second character is equal to an 1, J, Q, K, or A. I then want to set a Boolean for each of these cases. This is a blackjack program  am writing.

The deck is dealt and a single card is evaluated
Card is a string that a given a random value from an array of cards, the value would be something like "HK"

```
bool delt1 = card[1].Equals("1");
bool deltJ = card[1].Equals("J");
bool deltQ = card[1].Equals("Q");
bool deltK = card[1].Equals("K");
bool deltA = card[1].Equals("A");
```

But I receive an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error

any suggestion?

Comment: How many elements are in your array?

Comment: card is a string, it will hold a value of a random card, something like "HK" for king of hearts

Comment: If `card` is a string then it is a collection of `char` values. Why are you checking that a char is equal to a string?

Comment: @Peerkon can you confirm in the debugger before the exception is thrown that it *does* hold a 2-letter string?

Comment: I need to compare the second letter of the string to determine the value I am adding to a variable called playerTotal

Comment: Okay thanks, it wasn't returning a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably fix your problem but you likely have others:

```
bool delt1, deltJ, deltQ, deltK, deltA;
if (card.Length >= 2)
{
    delt1 = card[1].Equals('1');
    deltJ = card[1].Equals('J');
    deltQ = card[1].Equals('Q');
    deltK = card[1].Equals('K');
    deltA = card[1].Equals('A');
}
else
    throw new Exception("Not enough characters in card to perform this check");
```

Comment: I wouldn't throw an exception here to handle the logic flow.  Exceptions are for exceptional events.

Comment: @DarrenYoung - If the OP's card string isn't formed in the way they expect then I'd call that an *exceptional event*.

Comment: This is in no way a case where an event should be thrown. You have full control over the logic here, you should handle it accordingly and in a way less expensive than exceptions!

Comment: @DarrenYoung - You're debating exception handling technique which is completely unrelated to the point of my answer or the OP's question. If you want to debate the correct way to implement exception handling, SO is not the right place to do it. Feel free to ask a question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.